# C# How to fix mismatch of reference in manifest with the identity of downloaded assembly Microsoft.Playwright.dll

Tags: c#, playwright, excel-addins, playwright-dotnet

I developed an addin for MS Excel. The solution can be built and run on my computer smoothly. But running the published .exe gives error:

```
Name: ExcelAddIn1
From: file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Install/ExcelAddIn1.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly Microsoft.Playwright.dll.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

The version of Playwright is 1.42.0.

I've checked ExcelAddIn1.dll.manifest and it's exactly 1.42.0.
I also searched along the whole solution and every line involving Playwright version compiles.
I tried to use old version of it, as 1.38.0, but this error still given.
Also tried clean solution and rebuild, which didn't help.